# SSL Authentication with PEM files (cURL + PHP)

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I've already been able to do something similar on other websites, but now I'm having trouble authenticating using SSL certificate on a particular site. When I install the certificate in the browser, it works perfectly. But when I convert the .pfx file into .pem files and I try to use it with php + curl, it does not work.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www2.agencianet.fazenda.df.gov.br/Inicio/Restrita/';
$pemfile = __DIR__ . '/pubKEY.pem';
$keyfile = __DIR__ . '/priKEY.pem';

$ch = curl_init($url);
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,de;q=0.2,es;q=0.2,gl;q=0.2,nl;q=0.2",
        "Cache-Control:no-cache",
        "Connection:keep-alive",
        "Host:www2.agencianet.fazenda.df.gov.br",
        "Pragma:no-cache",
        "Referer:http://agnet.fazenda.df.gov.br/",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1",
        "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
    ),
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $pemfile,
    CURLOPT_SSLKEY => $keyfile,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE => 'PEM'
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($data);
print_r(curl_error($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```

The pem files are these:

> drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxSFCb666mqCbUJIMlhIMjh0aGM?usp=sharing

Some images:

[image: [Image 1]]
[image: [Image 2]]

Comment: Never share your private SSH key pairs like this.

Comment: Are keys only for testing.

Comment: On your page start error_reporting(E_ALL); and check using this condition. if(!$data) {  echo "Curl Error: " . curl_error($ch);} and edit your question with what error you found.

Comment: The error is that it is not authenticating with the passed keys. The site redirects to the login page.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 302 Redirect
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://www2.agencianet.fazenda.df.gov.br/Acesso/CertificadoDigital
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge, chrome=1
Server: 241
Date: Tue, 27 Dec 2016 11:05:18 GMT
Content-Length: 189

Comment: are you using post method for sending data ? because if you are sending some data on this url that you have to use  CURLOPT_POST and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS for it. If you are only fetching data then this code is ohk as per my knowledge.

Comment: No. As in image 2, the method is get.

Comment: This code works perfectly in other website, in this site that is giving problems.

Comment: So may be there is some problem with your key generation. Are your pem files are generated using passphrase ? If they used passphrase while key generation than you have to set this parameter. CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD

Comment: @Erlen if you are add image it should image not links.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9SJ6.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGbx2.png

Comment: The same pem files and the same code works perfectly in other website.